# Get null in createsocket with socketFactory in android

Tags: android, sslsocketfactory

I am writing code in android for connect server with SSL. Android does not support JKS, I use BKS, 
I do not put BKS file in server, I am connecting to server without BKS file in server, I put BKS file in my android's project, I get null in this line :

```
s = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(host,port);
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: I can resolve my problem with add this code:if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
       
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          
        }

Comment: But that is a bad hack. Only usefull temporarily. Better put that code in an AsyncTask or Thread.